# CSS appearance dooes not working even at MDN

Tags: appearance

I think CSS 'appearance' not working!

The examples in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance is not working for me now.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq2dq.png)

Is there any change by clicking the option in MDN example?

But i cant any information that browsers stop support 'appearance'.

Please let me know about why i cant use 'appearance'....